# Mod-M counter Unsigned values have no signal

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

I am writing a RS232 module for my Nexys2 board. I am currently having issues with my baud rate controller which I want to set to 19200.

For this I am using a Mod-M counter, after many ISim simulations the problem with my code is in the mod-m counter as it is not producing any ticks.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity baud_rate is
    generic (
    N: integer := 8;
    M: integer :=163);
    Port (clk, reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           tick : out  STD_LOGIC;
              q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0));

end baud_rate;

architecture Behavioral of baud_rate is
signal r_reg :  unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
signal r_next : unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
begin
process(clk,reset)
begin
    if (reset ='1') then
        r_reg <= (others=>'0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then 
    r_reg <= r_next;
    end if;
end process;

r_next <= (others =>'0') when r_reg=(M-1) else r_reg+1;
tick <='1' when r_reg=(M-1) else '0';
q <= std_logic_vector(r_reg);


end Behavioral;
```

I have tested and all the clk inputs and run fine and the issue seems to be with the r_reg and r_next registers. In ISim when outputing either of these on q I get UUUUUUUU, so it seems they are not generating signal. From this i can infer that the two r_reg and r_next registers aren't being created or storing values, is there an issue when using unsigned?

To make triple sure I have even copied the mod-m counter from the book FPGA Prototyping with VHDL (which is the code shown) BUT still this does not work and q output is UUUUUUUU.

If there are any better ways of creating a baud rate from the nexys2 50mz clock that would also be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Since you haven't shown us the testbench I have to ask : have you applied a reset signal? What happened to r_reg when you did? Also : this is pretty bad VHDL (though not so bad it's broken); did it really come from the Pong Chu book?

Comment: I have applied no reset signal, and yes it came from the book as I wanted to make sure it worked! But I did try taking the r_reg <= r_next outside of the clk event to check if the clock was the problem and still nothing

Comment: I didn't put up the test bench as all it is is passing in a clk signal and reading out tick and q (if you could point me to some better code it would greatly appreciated, even as a novice I found this pretty ugly!)

Comment: Well there you have your answer. The ONLY way out of r_reg = "UUUU" is in the Reset clause. I'll add an answer with tidier but untested VHDL.

Comment: thank you very much, I just forcing the reset to '1' on ISim and when I output r_reg I now get XXXXXXXX, so I think its now down to r_next being broken when I do r_reg <= r_next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly I am horrified if people are expected to learn VHDL from a book where examples like this are presented. I know the author has a similar book on Verilog : do people end up thinking VHDL is just a more verbose Verilog?

Specific criticisms (actually 7,8 are more observations):

1) Spurious type conversions.
Q represents an unsigned number. So make it unsigned!

The baud generator isn't the only thing in your FPGA so Q isn't likely to be an off-chip port. There are good arguments for making top level, off-chip ports std_logic_vector but even that isn't compulsory. However, if your customer's specification or coding style insists on spurious type conversions on ports; follow it.

2) the DRY principle:

```
package CPU_types is
    subtype baud_count is unsigned(7 downto 0);
end CPU_types;
```

Spot the simplification in maintenance.
If you are using a subtype in several places, put it in a package; the universal code reuse tool.

3) Indentation, formatting. (I recognise that may have become garbled by editor settings). It adds to the brain load reading it. What I've done here isn't The One Way though.

4) Spurious brackets round logical expressions. Harmless, but look like crutches for C programmers.

5) Antique clk'event style. Next year, the rising_edge function will be old enough to drink (in America. In Britain it's been getting plastered every Saturday night for a couple of years now...)

6) The "two process" style with r_reg and r_next. Does he also write state machines with a separate combinational process on next_state? Given this, I'm guessing so. Single process state machines are easier, smaller (to write : they don't generate smaller hardware) and safer.

7) I cheated and my tick is one cycle later than in the original. If that is critical, restore the external "tick" assignment. I also made it synchronous vhich will help performance. Some people would prefer `tick <= '0'` in an else clause; however the default assignment I used is safe, and prevents a lot of mistakes (and unnecessary else clauses) in larger designs.

8) The assignment to Q can be brought into the process too; if you made r_reg a process variable you'd have to. There is room for other variations and preferences.

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
    use CPU_types.all;

    entity baud_rate is
        generic (
            M: integer := 163);
        Port (
            clk, reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
            tick : out  STD_LOGIC;
            q    : out baud_count);  
    end baud_rate;

    architecture Behavioral of baud_rate is
        signal r_reg : baud_count;
    begin

    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if reset ='1' then
            r_reg <= (others=>'0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then 
            tick  <= 0;
            r_reg <= r_reg+1;
            if r_reg = M then 
                tick  <= '1';
                r_reg <= (others=>'0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

--    tick <='1' when r_reg = M-1 else '0';
--    or simpler, when r_reg = 0
    q <= r_reg;

    end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Cheers for a great answer, much appreciated!

Comment: `Single process state machines are easier, smaller (to write : they don't generate smaller hardware)` - they don't generate larger hardware either :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Considering how ugly the original code is I may well have overlooked something, but shouldn't the line `if r_reg = M then` actually be `if r_reg = M-1 then`? I think the way you coded it causes r_reg to count from 0 to M inclusive, which would cause your ticks to be one cycle further apart than in the original. Note that r_reg is not a variable, so the assignment `r_reg <= r_reg+1;` will not affect the if statement!

Comment: @Zennehoy : quite right! Now, if R_Reg had been a variable instead of a signal, my code would have been correct! (because it is tested after the increment). Of course we don't know where the magic value for M came from. The generic ought to be the baud rate, and M ought to be an internal constant, calculated from it and the clock period...

Comment: hi, i am just testing it now, sorry I had a busy afternoon, but will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, tick is not driven and q is still xxxxxxxx, but a huge thanks for the tips it has really helped if all else has failed!

Comment: Though I did just realise that there is some action, after after 60ps the tick line goes from U->0 and q goes from UUUUUUUU -> XXXXXXXX so something is happening. I'll have a tinker and let you know

Comment: Even when driving the reset to 1 and then setting it back to 0 after 20ps it appears q is still XXXXXXXX. From this I conclude this is a problem in setting up the r_reg (which is also the problem with the initial code), but I really can't see anything wrong!

Comment: One thing you could try (and preferably get in the habit of) is initializing your signals. Change the signal declaration for r_reg to: `signal r_reg : baud_count := (others=>'0');` and see if that helps.

Comment: @zennehoy : it's not a bad habit, but here it may obscure proper understanding what's going on. A better suggestion would be a VHDL testbench that runs for several clock periods. (Set the generic to 5 or something when you instantiate the counter in the TB. Saves waiting!)

Comment: it has been solved, the problem was I needed the tick after so used the later tick assignment, the problem was something to do with the have the r_reg being handled outside the process.